# How to find which element stands higher in the DOM hierarchy?

Tags: javascript, dom, hierarchy

I mean, how can I find which of two elements belongs to a node nearest to 'document' or 'window'? which is higher in hierarchy?

EDIT
this gets the job done:

```
function gerarchia(elem) { 
  var i=0; 
  while (elem.parentNode) { 
    elem = elem.parentNode; 
    i++; 
  } 
  return i; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `.parents().length`, like this:

```
if ( $(element1).parents().length > $(element2).parents().length ) {
  // lower
}
else {
  // higher
}
```

Comment: Should probably point out that this would require jquery as jquery was not included in the tags of the question.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better way, but the brute force approach of just calling `parentNode` repeatedly with a counter until you hit the root should work.  Assuming your document isn't nested ridiculously deep, it should be relatively quick.

Comment: thanks for the hint.. I came up with this function which seems to get the job done.

`function gerarchia(elem) {
 var i=0;
 while (elem.parentNode) {
  elem = elem.parentNode;
  i++;
 }
 return i;
}`

Answer (score 0):

If you've got jQuery, you can just do this to find, for example, the first `<li>` element:

```
$('li:first')
```